# For Range in Zip

Tags: python, for-loop, range, zip

I'm writing an api code. He pulls the token and id from the list, then goes back to the beginning and pulls the 2nd token and the 2nd id. I made a loop like this. But how do I add range into the for loop. So I want this loop to turn 10 times. How do I add Range.

```
import requests
import json
token = [line.strip() for line in open("./dosya/tokenler/1.txt")]
ids = [line.strip() for line in open("./dosya/tokenler/data.txt")]
for tokenn, idcek in zip(token, ids):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Authorization': tokenn
    }

    data = {
        "to_id": "56822556", "from_id": idcek
        }

    response = requests.post("https://sitelink.com", headers=headers, json=data)


print(response.text)
```

Comment: If you want to repeat your existing for loop 10 times, you can wrap your existing for loop with an outer for loop `for _ in range(10):`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work because the for loop inside the outer for doesn't return to the beginning before it is completely finished. I need to add it to my existing for.

Comment: How can I add how many times For has to run? I'm asking because I don't know. Can you help me?

Comment: To clarify - you want the existing for loop to run 10 times, even if there are less than 10 items in `tokenn` or `idcek`?

Comment: There are 500 tokens in the token and idcek. When I run the code like this, it pulls 500 times, but I want it to pull 100 times. How can I limit this to range. Let this for loop run 100 times, then stop.I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your existing for loop to run 100 times, you can use `enumerate()` to get the "loop index" as well, then stop the for loop on the 101th run (index 100):

```
for idx, (tokenn, idcek) in enumerate(zip(token, ids)):
    if idx == 100:
        # loop ran 100 times already, exiting loop
        break

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Authorization': tokenn
    }

    data = {
        "to_id": "56822556", "from_id": idcek
    }

    """existing code"""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance what limit you want on the iteration, you can add that as a component of the zip:

```
lim = 100
for tokenn, idcek, _ in zip(token, ids, range(lim)):
     # etc
```

You don't need to look at it; the zip will just terminate on the shortest input.